# Hide css border triangle behind a tag

Tags: css

I have a responsive layout

```html
<div class='large-2 columns'>
  <div class='menu_item'>
    <p>
      <a href='/example'>Linktext</a>
      <span class='arrow'></span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The arrow class on span creates an css triangle arrow (with the border-width: 2px 2px 0px trick). Normally the p has enough width to display the Linktext and the css triangle arrow next to each other. The triangle arrow is positioned absolute on the right hand side of the p tag. The p content should be one line height heigh (no line break).
When I am resizing the liquid layout for some not primarily important window/screen sizes, the width of the p is smaller than would be needed for the linktext and the arrow right next to it.
In this case, when the arrow doesn't fit next to the link text in the p tag, which width is given from the responsive layout, I want the arrow to be hidden behind the link text (like a has background white and a higher z index for example). However, this solution with background/z index didn't seem to work.

*edit* reformulated question as it seemed unclear, removed confusing fiddle

Comment: You want it behind or hide it completely?

Comment: can you explain the question once again.. its really difficult to understand

Comment: text-indent about equal to span width https://jsfiddle.net/9nvGM/23/ ? z-index, or the use of a pseudo within the flow ?

Comment: @GCyrillus I think OP mentioned some arrow with the question..?

Comment: @TusharGupta mistake with fiddle link pasted , updated , the point is that question is unclear actually :)

Comment: Do you want it right next to the link or hide it completely? Please clarify what you're trying to do...

Comment: I tried to explain myslef better and removed the fiddle as it seems to rather confuse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works by adding the following to css (sass) -

```
a
  background: white
  display: inline-block
```

and placing the span before the a in the source code